# A template for a book

Tags: front-matter

I am looking for a template for the front page of my book in LaTeX.

Is there a source from where I may get one?

Comment: Hope this may helps to you.... https://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book and https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/the-legrand-orange-book-template-english/jtctyfmnpppc

Answer (score 1):

The `memoir` class provides the tools for making title pages, see "Chapter 4: Titles" in the manual (`> texdoc memoir`).

My *A Few Notes on Book Design* (`> texdoc memdesign`) shows some 14 examples of title pages.